# install php and composer inside jenkins container

Tags: php, docker, jenkins, composer-php, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to create a Jenkins pipeline that has a 'Test' stage which requires PHP and Composer in order to run the tests with PHPUnit.

How do I install PHP (preferably version 7.4) and Composer inside a Jenkins Docker container?

This is how I tried inside the container's Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins

USER root

# install PHP and Composer
RUN apt-get install -y php php-mbstring php-xml php-bcmath && \
    apt-get install -y composer
    
USER jenkins
```

When I build the image I get this error:

```
Step 3/4 : RUN apt-get install -y php php-mbstring php-xml php-bcmath php-fpm &&     apt-get install -y composer && apt-get install -y vim
 ---> Running in 0b20c56bd720
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package php
E: Unable to locate package php-mbstring
E: Unable to locate package php-xml
E: Unable to locate package php-bcmath
E: Unable to locate package php-fpm
```

Comment: Which parts of that error message are unclear? How is this related to Composer if installing PHP dependencies already failed?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You miss `apt-get update` before `install`.

> The sudo apt-get update command is used to download package information from all configured sources

See [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-does-sudo-apt-get-update-command-do-on-ubuntu-debian/).

Comment: Thank you, this installs php version 7.0. Now I'm trying to install php 7.4, if I add "apt-get install software-properties-common && \ add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php && \ apt-get install -y php7.4" I get error "Service 'jenkins' failed to build" if I rebuild the image.